# Create EFI System partition Debian installation

Tags: debian-installer

In Ubuntu you can select EFI System Partition during installation:

[image]

What is the equivalent configuration within Debian 11 installer using [amd64 iso](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/)? Which File System, Mount Point and Flags should be selected?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below is valid only for EFI x86-64 systems:

- It's ESP or the **E**FI (Extensible Firmware Interface) **S**ystem **P**artition
- Filesystem must be `FAT32`
- Mount point must be `/boot/efi`
- No flags are necessary
- Nowadays it's recommended to allocate at least 500MB to it.

Comment: I use [amd64 iso](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/) there is no `/boot/efi` mount point available. With respect to my question, is there equivalent configuration for amd64 iso?

Comment: I meant x86-64 as well. So, it's valid.

Comment: As I said, there is no mount point `/boot/efi` provided by the installer.

Comment: You should not be restricted to the drop-down list: it should be possible to just type in whatever you want.